# What is the correct command to produce small wedges in differential forms?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

In a differential form (see, for example, Definition 10.11 in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*):

[image]

there are wedge-like symbols. I found two plausible commands to produce them: `\wedge` and `\land`. In appearance, they look indistinguishable. So which one should be adopted?

Comment: They *are* indistinguishable: both are `\mathchar"225E`.

Comment: I see, thank you. Just for curiosity, then why designers used two different commands?

Comment: In the hope that users would remember at least one of them! (;-)  Seriously, `\wedge` is reminiscent of the shape, while `\land` alludes to one of the most widespread meanings.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. Aside from any opinion, there are clearly-defined considerations for which should be used, as evident from the answer.

Comment: noone adressed the "small" in the caption.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [noted in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314296/what-is-the-correct-command-to-produce-small-wedges-in-differential-forms#comment766553_314296) the two symbols are indistinguishable.

When typing differential forms, use the command `\wedge` since the symbol *is* called the wedge product. (Similarly when you do [wedge sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) in topology.)

Use `\land` when you use the symbol as the "logical and" symbol.

When writing notes in lattice theory I would sometimes also define `\newcommand*\meet{\wedge}` to give yet another name to the same symbol (and to reflect its name in the theory).

Synonyms can help make your source code more readable.

---

See also [this question and its answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23799/why-land-instead-of-and).

Comment: Very convincing explanation, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The explanation for the dual naming is in the following lines of `plain.tex`

```
837 \mathchardef\wedge="225E \let\land=\wedge
838 \mathchardef\vee="225F \let\lor=\vee
```

So `\land` is just an alias for `\wedge` and similarly for `\lor`.

LaTeX used to load a slightly modified version of `plain.tex`; when LaTeX2e was released, the aliases were kept for compatibility reasons in `fontmath.ltx`:

```
270 \DeclareMathSymbol{\wedge}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"5E}
271    \let\land=\wedge
272 \DeclareMathSymbol{\vee}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"5F}
273    \let\lor=\vee
```

(line numbers added for reference).

So what name you use is irrelevant. However, if a package redefines `\wedge` to point to another symbol, the meaning of `\land` would be unaffected.